# How to calibrate monitor in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: monitor, mate, monitor-calibration

**Question:**

How can I calibrate my monitor in Ubuntu Mate without extra hardware?

**Details:**

I have installed [`gnome-color-manager`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-color-manager) but no gui is available and I can't find an ICC profile file for my monitor to use in command line.

Also, I tried to compile [`mate-color-manager`](https://github.com/NiceandGently/mate-color-manager) but it is obsolete and requires old version of `mate-desktop` package.

Finally, I tried [dispcalGUI](http://dispcalgui.hoech.net/) but later I found that it requires a [measurement device](http://dispcalgui.hoech.net/#quickstart).

So, at the moment, I have not had success with any of the options I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do any real calibration without extra hardware. Bare minimum is a colorimeter but you really want spectrometer. Unfortunately, spectrometers come with high costs (second hand devices cost at least $150) and colorimeters not really suitable for LED backlighting which majority of the LCD displays are using nowadays. The `ColorHug2` is claiming to be an exception because it uses much higher quality sensor than typical colorimeters.

The best you can do without any extra hardware is to adjust monitor settings according to test images (e.g. http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/) and then adjust gamma ramp by running `xgamma -gamma <some number between 0.5 and 2.0>` until the gamma test image reads that the actual gamma is `2.2`. Figuring out the correct number for the `-gamma` argument is trial and error. Try `1.0` first and if gamma is below `2.2` according to test image, you have to decrease your current gamma value. (My monitors have always used `xgamma` gamma between `0.9` and `1.2` but low quality displays can be all over the place. My "factory calibrated" monitor requires `0.92`.) After that, just pretend that your display is a calibrated sRGB monitor. If you have a laptop where only display adjustment available is the brightness of backlight, there's really not much to do.

And if you're happy with your display currently, do not visit http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/ because the more you understand the flaws in your display the less happy you will be...

**Update 2024:** It seems that `lagom.nl` is no longer maintained so the test patterns should be accessed via Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20240225143253/http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/

And it seems that ColorHug2 is no longer sold and the web site no longer mentions the device.

Comment: Even after upvoting your answer, its points are still on zero, which means someone downvoted it for no apparent reason.

Comment: calibrate means colour adjustment usually.  colour is adjusted by terminal commands. 
suppose you want less green and blue....command ... 
xgamma -rgamma 1.0 -ggamma 0.9 -bgamma 0.8

Comment: brightness and contrast can be adjusted by the zoom option, after installing tweaks.

Comment: If you adjust brightness and contrast computationally, you'll be limiting the bit depth of your display. Sure, that's better than having no control but it's far from optimal situation.